# How to Speed the update to the image element in PysimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am using PysimpleGUI's Image element, in which I am updating the image element after a frame received from the camera or sometime updating with same data if none is received

the recording from the camera is handle in a separate thread while the updating element is in main thread

the issue is regarding the time taken to update a single element which is about 60 ms and for 16 elements it is about 0.5s which is too high
Due to this there is a lag effect in visualisation

Here is the code to test for you guys, let me know how can i speedup the updation of elements because i am going to use same for 32 image elements

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import cv2
import time

video_capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def layouting(_format, window_name):
    if _format == '1x1':
        layout = [[sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "11",
                            right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True)]]
        return layout

    elif _format == '16_':
        layout = [[
            sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "11",
                     right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
            sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "12",
                     right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
            sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "13",
                     right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
            sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "14",
                     right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True)
        ],
            [
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "21",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "22",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "23",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "24",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True)
            ],
            [
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "31",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "32",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "33",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "34",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True)
            ],
            [
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "41",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "42",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "43",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True),
                sg.Image(filename='A1_Logo.png', key=f"{window_name}" + "44",
                         right_click_menu=['R&ight', ['Add Camera', 'Remove']], enable_events=True)
            ]]
        return layout

camera_no = 16
select_layout = "16_"    #'16_' or '1x1' change for 16 and 1 element layout respectively
select_window = 'window-1'

window = sg.Window('AI-VMS',layouting(select_layout, select_window),resizable=True,size=(900,900),location=(500,20),icon='a1-fence-logo.ico',element_justification='center',finalize=True)
window.maximize()

element_keys = list(window.AllKeysDict.keys())

while True:

    event,values = window.read(timeout=5)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    ret, frameOrig = video_capture1.read()
    start = time.time()
    for i in element_keys:
        if select_layout == "16_":
            frame = cv2.resize(frameOrig, (int(window.size[0]/4.2),int(window.size[1]/4.2)))
        else:
            frame = cv2.resize(frameOrig, (window.size[0], window.size[1]))
        imgbytes = cv2.imencode(".png", frame)[1].tobytes()
        window[i].update(data=imgbytes)
    print(time.time() - start)


video_capture1.release()
window.close()
```

the above example has 1 cv2 read and displaying that on all over the 16 element which take around more that 150ms, i am expecting the update to finish in microseconds or 10 to 20 millsecond max

kindly help with your thoughts and how to manage camera and UI in software
is there any industry standard practise

Comment: Why do you call `cv2.resize()` and `cv2.imencode()` inside the for loop? They can be called once before the for loop.

Comment: this was an example of what i am doing unfortunately i won't able to share code here.
so i will try to explain what i am doing
i have a dictionary which gets data from the opencv thread and holds the data
the job of resize is so that all the element is not necessary to have same size (You can imagine a VMS example where some image are big and some are small)

Comment: each key in dictionary updates with the latest frame from camera ,then the images are resize to fit in the element size(mostly the element uses this size for resizing)
and also there is not one opencv object,16 elements means 16 opencv object which fetches data from different ip cams

Comment: i have doubt regarding the update rate for the elements ,i have Tried PyQt which updates 16 elements in 5ms to 10ms time ,which remove the lag effect.
and i also tried pysimpleguiqt variant even that shows same result it takes 0.5s to update 16 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time to update 16 images maybe just about under 50ms.
There's more time required because you do the job to resize and encode the image for update.

```py
from time import time
from random import randint
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def image_to_data(im):
    """
    Image object to bytes object.
    : Parameters
      im - Image object
    : Return
      bytes object.
    """
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

# Prepare images for Image update

images = []
width, height = size = (350, 150)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
for i in range(16):
    im = Image.new("RGBA", size, 'blue')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((width//2, height//2), f"Image {i}", fill='white', anchor="mm", font=font)
    images.append(image_to_data(im))

class Image(sg.Image):

    # Auto key for Image element
    index = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({
            "data":images[randint(0, 15)],
            "size":size,
            "key":f"Image {Image.index}"
        })
        Image.index += 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

layout = [[Image() for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout)


while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        old = time()
        for i in range(16):
            window[f"Image {i}"].update(data=images[randint(0, 15)])
        now = time()
        print(f"{int((now - old)*1000)}ms")
        old = now

window.close()
```